# Cloth and smoke simulation not working

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation, cloth-simulation

So I was creating a smoke sim (in 2.82) and had a cloth fall onto the smoke to act as an obstacle, so that it would collide with the smoke, however it did not. I have set the cloth to be an effector but it won't move the smoke what so ever. What setting is there to help with this?[image]

Comment: Have you tried checking `Is Planar` and turning up the surface thickness?

Comment: I did not do it before, it now works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comment worked, here it is as an actual answer:

When your collision object has no thickness, you either need to add thickness (e.g. by using solidify), or check the Is Planar box, and fake thickness with the Surface Thicknesss slider.

[image: Checking Is Planar]

A lower value will be more realistic, but risk smoke passing straight through, while higher values will more likely stop the smoke, but might look weird as the smoke will stop before reaching the geometry.